# Creating and comparing intervals of time in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a database of individuals' addresses in SAS like this:

```
OBS    ID    addresstype    effectivedate    enddate    postalcode

1      1          M            Feb2000       Jan2003      A1A1A1    
2      1          R            Jan2003       Jan2020      B2B2B2
3      1          M            Feb2016       Sep2016      C3C3C3
4      1          M            Sep2016       Jan2020      D4D4D4
```

Addresses are either residential (R) or mailing (M).
For each individual and for each period of time, if I have the residential address I want to keep that and delete any mailing address in that period of time. If for a period of time there is no residential address recorded, then I will keep the mailing address. For the individual of this example I want the clean data to look like this:

```
OBS   ID    addresstype    effectivedate    enddate    postalcode

1     1          M            Feb2000       Jan2003      A1A1A1    
2     1          R            Jan2003       Jan2020      B2B2B2
```

Is there any way in SAS to create intervals of time based on two dates (effectivedate and enddate in this example) and then compare them against each other.    Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every customer will have 1 Residential address, 
1)

1. You could divide the dataset into two - ds_M and ds_R.
2. `impute` dates and concatenate 01 in effectiveDate and 30 in the enddate in
   each datasets and convert them to numeric using `input` function and `date9.` format
3. rename the columns in ds_R , addresstype(you can drop it while merging in next step too), effectiveDate & enddate
4. `merge` the datasets and compare the intervals, you can mark each row with
   flags and then subset basis that - call this dataset ds_semi
5. `append` both ds_semi & ds_R to create the final one

Alternatively, you can do step number 2 in main dataset then check out `point 
 option` of `set` and how to do one normal `set` and another `set` in a `do loop` that might create a similar output for you. However this may need a bit of preprocessing beforehand but it will do the thing in one step.

You can refer my code below I once used to solve a similar problem of finding difference in values in multiple rows to make decision and assigning value -

`data y /*output dataset*/;
  set x(rename = ( x = k )) nobs = nobs  ; /*renaming variable x to k for making calculations */
    do i = 1 to _n_+1 ; /*iterating from 1 to current obseration in PDV + 1 */
       if  mod(i , 2) = 0 /*checking if observation is even or not*/ then do ;
          set x point = i ; /*setting same source dataset with POINT so that we can slice the dataset on even observation.
                              It will leave only required value for our next statement.*/
             y = x  ; /*assigning variable x to y so that we can calculate the difference.*/
             diff = k - y ;
       end ;
    end ;
  if mod(_n_, 2) ne 0 then output ;
run ;`